# Command line to invoke hg histedit to edit last commit?

Tags: mercurial

Is something like `hg histedit edit --rev -1` command 1-liner possible to edit the last commit? I wanted to skip choosing the `edit` operation in the CUI.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but why not `hg commit --amend`?

Comment: This is a good approach in general, but will only work if you are editing a head. Histedit can edit interstitial commits which is more flexible and often more useful.